# Jquery - Slide up new html table row instead of Slidedown like rediffmail

Tags: jquery

I have a html table, when i click any `tr` it is displaying a new `tr` after clicked 'row' with slide down options. It's working fine.

But i need to display this new dynamic `tr` row using *slideUp* then *slideDown* options like `rediff mail`. If u login with *rediffmail*, when we click any mail it will display new row with *slideUp* option again we clicked that row, new row will be hide with *slideDown* option.

How to i achieve this using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question, but this might help...

slideUp() does not function well on table rows because they have no height associated, instead tables adjust to fit the contents within. To get around this, wrap a div around contents within each td on the row and then animate those divs.

As an example, this will slideUp() and remove() a table row correctly:

```
rw.find("td").wrapInner("<div>");
rw.find("td div:not(:last)").slideUp();
rw.find("td div:last").slideUp(function(){ rw.remove(); });
```